# custom Entries filter in jQueryDatatable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datatables

I want to create custom entries filter in jquery datatable

```
<select name="admin_length" size="1" aria-controls="admin"><option
                                    value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
                                <option value="25">25</option>
                                <option value="50">50</option>
                                <option value="100">100</option></select>
```

this is located outside from the table

Answer (score 0):

use change event of dropdown and match your condition with each row of table.
something like this

```
    $("#admin_length").change(function(){
       $("#table tr").each( function(index){
       var cellText=($("this").children(tr:nth-child(1)).text();
    //according to you filter condition on cellText show or hide current row (this)

    })    
})
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="admin_length" name="admin_length" size="1" aria-controls="admin"><option
                                    value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
                                <option value="25">25</option>
                                <option value="50">50</option>
                                <option value="100">100</option></select>
```

and use this jquery code

$('#admin_length').change(function(){

oTable.api().columns().search( $(this).val() ).draw();

})